# Magento 2 with Porto theme customization

Tags: magento2

I'm totally new to Magento... I have been working on a theme called Porto for Magento 2... I have manage to modify many things that I required but cannot seems to modify the highlighted part.

Please can anyone help me from where in magento admin I can edit that area?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify that part from admin.

In Magento admin,

```
Content -> Pages
```

Edit page, which is set as current homepage. You can find code in page content section.

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya, Can you please tell me , how to add sidemenu on homepage? i am also using magento2.2.4 porto theme.